# Conversion of date format %B %Y

Tags: r, date

Can we somehow convert dates such as `"November 2017", "December 2017"` to date? I tried to import csv data, but received factor columns.

I tried the following code, but was not successful.

```
as.POSIXct(as.character(dat$Date), format = "%B %Y")
```

Comment: Caveat: `%B` is the *Full month name **in the current locale.*** (Emphasis mine).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick solution from `lubridate` package

```
dmy(paste("01", dat$Date))
```

Answer (score 6):

A `POSIXct` date needs the day of the month to be complete and valid.
You can add it to the date strings, then use the format `"%B %Y %d"` e.g. :

```
as.POSIXct(paste(as.character(dat$Date),"01"), format = "%B %Y %d")
```

BTW, when you import a csv you can set `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` (as argument of `read.csv/read.table` functions) to obtain characters instead of factors.

Answer (score 4):

The argument `truncated` does the job:

```
 library(lubridate)
 myd("November 2017", truncated = 1)
 # "2017-11-01"
```

Comment: Excellent use of `lubridate` and its `truncated`  parameter.

Comment: @Uwe - Except it gives the wrong result (`"2020-11-17"`)

Comment: @RichScriven Of course, I had tested it before posting the comment. On my system, `lubridate::myd("November 2017", truncated = 1)` returns `"2017-11-01"`. Would be interesting to understand why you got a different result than Enrique or me.

Comment: @RichScriven One possible explanation for the different results might be that  `help("parse_date_time", package = "lubridate")` says: *The C parser currently understands only English month names.*

Answer (score 1):

A proposition with the [`zoo`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/zoo.pdf) package:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","English")
#> [1] "English_United States.1252"
zoo::as.yearmon("November 2017", '%B %Y')
#> [1] "Nov 2017"
zoo::as.Date(zoo::as.yearmon("November 2017", '%B %Y'))
#> [1] "2017-11-01"
Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME","French")
#> [1] "French_France.1252"
zoo::as.yearmon("Novembre 2017", '%B %Y')
#> [1] "nov. 2017"

# Created on 2021-02-03 by the reprex package (v0.3.0.9001)
```

Regards,