# Can a datepart be parsed as date object, directly without concatenating the missing datepart

Tags: r, date

Suppose I have a character vector `dt` with some months-years stored as character format-

```
dt <- c("Mar-19", "Apr-19", "May-19")
```

when I try to convert it into date object, it returns NAs only

```
as.Date(dt, format = "%b-%y")
[1] NA NA NA
```

So I have to first concatenate a `dummy` date say `01` to each object and then parse it as date and thereafter format the vector to show it in original format

```
format.Date(as.Date(paste0("01-", dt), format = "%d-%b-%y"), "%b-%y")

[1] "Mar-19" "Apr-19" "May-19"
```

Is there any direct method to parse a `truncated date`/`datepart` directly without concatenating and thus avoiding the long route?

Comment: What's the difference between input and output?

Comment: Input is of character type but output is of datetype

Comment: @jay.sf Thanks for reading my post. Actually I want to convert the data type of vector without concatenating but also without changing the output format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zoo` has `as.yearmon` class and function which can convert data with year and month without the date.

```
dt <- c("Mar-19", "Apr-19", "May-19")
zoo::as.yearmon(dt, '%b-%y')
```

To get it in character class you can use `format` with format as required.

```
format(zoo::as.yearmon(dt, '%b-%y'), '%b-%y')
#[1] "Mar-19" "Apr-19" "May-19"
```

Comment: Exactly this was I looking for

Comment: So can these be used as datepart objects while arranging or calculating difference between two elements?

Comment: Yes, you can perform different calculations on these objects. Also note that the class of `as.yearmon` is `"yearmon"` and not `"Date"`. Although you can get a date object by wrapping `as.Date` i.e `as.Date(zoo::as.yearmon(dt, '%b-%y'))`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `readr::parse_date` for this, but it is still not elegant

```r
library(tidyverse)

dt <- c("Mar-19", "Apr-19", "May-19")

dt %>% parse_date(format = "%b-%y") %>% format("%b-%y")
#> [1] "Mar-19" "Apr-19" "May-19"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
dt <- c("Mar-19", "Apr-19", "May-19")
lubridate::myd(dt, truncated = 1)
#> [1] "2019-03-01" "2019-04-01" "2019-05-01"

# Created on 2021-02-01 by the reprex package (v0.3.0.9001)
```

(Related to [Conversion of date format %B %Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996574/conversion-of-date-format-b-y))

Regards,

Comment: Good but it changes the format of output which isn't desired

Comment: You can apply the desired format : `format.Date(lubridate::myd(dt, truncated = 1), "%b-%y")`